# OnClick attribute causing error after upgrading .net from 1.1 to 2.0

Tags: .net, xslt

Everything worked fine in 1.1, but after upgrading to 2.0 im getting a parse error saying my Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode does not have public property named OnClick.  I give it said attribute in an xslt file as so:

```
<xsl:attribute name="OnClick">
    <xsl:value-of select="OnClick" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

What changed with this attribute between the two versions?

Further explanation: I have a data relation with categories, and under each category will be a   link to a different report. The relation is converted to xml, and then transformed using the xslt file.  After the upgrade, the onclick of these links doesnt work.  I comment that section of the xslt file out.  The treeview loads with all of the parent categories, but when i try to click on one to expand it out to show the links, everything disappears.

Link to my .net sub http://snipt.org/spmkg5.
Link to xslt file: http://snipt.org/spmkh8

I know the sub is a bit of a mess to look at but if i could get some advice it would be great.

Comment: Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode

Comment: I think treenode swithed namespaces as it was new in 2.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Yea it looks like OnClick was removed in 2.0. Not sure what to use instead.  I might have to use a different control.

Comment: Use treeview if you can. Your onclick would move/map to SelectedNodeChanged on the TreeView. Or you could still use the old control but in that case you need to register it at the top of the page. Not sure though if it is compatible with 2.0

Comment: I am using a treeview. the xslt file is setting the properties of each treenode inside the treeview.

Comment: I updated my question with more explanation and the code im using to bind my treeview

Comment: Can you write the xml from this statement to a file and also snipt that:  dsNavTree.GetXml()

Comment: trying to get ahold of it.  Im at work and am having difficulty stepping into the code because of authentication nonsense.  When i get it figured out i will post it.

Comment: ok here it is http://snipt.org/sppu6

Comment: Well, after reading up and trying to grasp what Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode should or can do, I can only say that you have no other option than to remove OnClick from your XSLT and find another way to hookup functionality. It seems the new version only has events for OnCollapse, OnExpand and OnSelectionChnaged. You should try to get without errors at this line trvReportCatalog.DataBind() and then try to hookup any events.

Comment: Is there a way i can reference an older assembly of treeview so i can still use onclick?